# Deploying war with custom context in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

I have a Tomcat server fronted by Apache with comms using AJP. The configuration uses JkMount for mapping URLs on Apache to the Tomcat node.

I am helping in the deployment of an application which is built using Maven and therefore is delivered in the form of a file named "my-war-3.0.1.war".

We can do a JkMount declaration of the following style:

```
JkMount /my-war-3.0.1 my-node
JkMount /my-war-3.0.1/* my-node
```

But obviously that requires the version number. New releases will mean updating the mounting and the users' bookmarks etc, which obviously isn't a Good Thing.

What I would like is to be able to have the JkMount declaration in the following style:

```
JkMount /my-war my-node
JkMount /my-war/* my-node
```

But I'm pretty sure that means that the .war file needs to be named in the same way.

I'm pretty sure it's possible to tell Tomcat to deploy a specified .war under another name using Context file fragments, but all I seem to get are error messages about the war being deployed inside the AppBase.

The environment I'm working in is quite locked down - it would be a lot of testing to be able to change the environment's configuration, so deploying a Context fragment file as a kind of deliverable would be a nice solution.

Is this possible, and if so what should the Context file be and where should it go?

I am using Tomcat 6.0.14, and as I said before, the environment is pretty locked down so it would be a lot of trouble to modify Tomcat configurations/folder structures.

The other solution is of course to remove the version number from the deliverable name, which is acceptable from the point of view of the development team, but I think everyone would prefer that the deliverable had the version number in its name for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing comes to my mind is creating a symlink for your webapp. Whenever you change the version, just re-create a symlink.

```
ln -s /path/to/tomcat/webapps/my-war-3.0.1 /path/to/tomcat/webapps/my-war
```

And then, create a `context.xml` file in `webapps/my-war-3.0.1/WEB-INF` to enable symlinks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/my-war" allowLinking="true">

</Context>
```